# Modify SQL result on the fly?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, sql

I have an SQL query : 
`SELECT DATEDIFF(deadline,CURDATE()) FROM tasks WHERE 1`

The Result is : `3`

How can I return the result as : `3 Days` instead of `3`

I know that I can manually append the string from my C# code something like :

```
 string result = getSqlresult();
 string result += " Days";
```

But I want to get the result directly as `3 Days` from MySQL database.

**The reason :** 
I'm binding information directly to datagridview and therefore, In order to modify the result i need to iterate through all rows and update them. So to increase performance, I need to get the result directly from database as `3 Days` instead of `3`

Anyhelp would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can concatenate the string `Days` into the result of `DATEDIFF` using `CONCAT`.

```
SELECT CONCAT(DATEDIFF(deadline,CURDATE()), ' Days') 
FROM tasks 
WHERE 1
```

if you are using old versions of `MySQL`, convert it to string so you will not get `bolb` result.

```
SELECT CONCAT(CAST(DATEDIFF(deadline,CURDATE()) AS CHAR(5)), ' Days') 
FROM tasks 
WHERE 1
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT  CASE 
            WHEN DATEDIFF(deadline,CURDATE()) >= 0
            THEN CONCAT(DATEDIFF(deadline,CURDATE()), ' Days')
            ELSE CONCAT('Expired since ', DATEDIFF(deadline,CURDATE()) * -1, ' Days')
        END
FROM    tasks
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c54304/3)

Comment: I don't believe it was that easy ! Thanks for answer

Comment: Is there someway on how can i display `Date expired` if the value of DATEDIFF() is negative ?

Comment: No ! Only if the value is strictly negative it displays something like `Expired since 3 days`

Comment: you're welcome `:D` by the way there was a typo error on the case statement but i updated the answer with demo `:D`